# .htaccess url masking

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a couple of wordpress urls that I want to simplify for SEO purposes. I have 
http://www.example.com/fr/product-fr/review-fr/

I would like to change that to http://www.example.com/fr/product/review/ (remove -fr) but without changing the URL internally. So the user would access http://www.example.com/fr/product/review/ but the server would serve the content of http://www.example.com/fr/product-fr/review-fr/.

I want to do this to get around a URL problem with Wordpress and WPML.

Appreciate the help

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `mod_rewrite` and `Rewrite rules`?

Try:

```
^/([a-zA-Z]{2})/([^\/]+)/([^\/]+)/$    /$1/$2-$1/$3-$1
```

Haven't tested this though..

Comment: yes but could not get anything to work. Here is a simple example I was trying 

RewriteRule ^about/$ about-es/

This should serve www.example.com/es/about-es/ but the user would see www.example.com/es/about/ as a url.

Comment: It did not work :( Thanks again for your help but I still got a 404 when access http://www.example.com/es/about/

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the two letter lang code is always going to be constant throughout the URL:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z]{2})/product/review$    /$1/product-$1/review-$1 [L,QSA]
```

should work a treat :)

P.S. the regexp takes any two-letter code (upper or lower case) so will work with other langs should you require.

Comment: Thanks for your help but it did not work. I tried the following for my wordpress installation. I used it on our about page. The problem is that I need it to be a bit more generic than that. It's for every page in the wordpress installation. Thanks again.    

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z]{2})/about$ /$1/about-$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]